# Google docs - get table row height via Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to get actual table cell height using only Google script ?

I have table, and I want to run script which colour cell, when cell become bigger than its minimal height.

Comment: I don't think so - getHeight returns the number of cells selected vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible using google apps script.